# Problem when i am accessing ActiveX DLL from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Good morning.

I have to access the active x dll which is installed on my system from VB.net.
I added as reference and followed all the steps as given in 
I have declared 
private mycomponent as activexcomponent.libclass

and i gave constructor for this i.e. creating the object for this class in the constructor of the main form as 
mycomponet = new activexcomponent.libclass()

Then the following expection is coming when i tried to run the program.

> System.InvalidOperationException: An
>   error occurred creating the form. See
>   Exception.InnerException for details. 
>   The error is: Creating an instance of
>   the COM component with CLSID
>   {D8A27DFF-A4B8-440E-8571-71A37D39403E}
>   from the IClassFactory failed due to
>   the following error: 800a0196. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Creating an instance of the COM
>   component with CLSID
>   {D8A27DFF-A4B8-440E-8571-71A37D39403E}
>   from the IClassFactory failed due to
>   the following error: 800a0196.

I have registered the activex dll. I tried my best to figure out the problem but could not succeed in this.
Please can any one help me out?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's not a standard HRESULT so you should really read the documentation or contact the developers of the ActiveX control to find out from them what it means. However, I did find comments that for some control it meant that it needs to be shown as modal, so you could try making the form modal (show it using `ShowDialog`) and see if that makes any difference.